# Manage display not updating user account display

Tags: entities

This is a new D7.14 site started only 3 days ago. There is no use of organic groups in this site. I added several fields (i.e. First Name, Last Name, City, State, Zip - as text and list fields). I set these to show on user registration form and to display publicly. I came back about a day later and changed the display settings on User Account to hide the labels and to change the display order. I also hid one of the fields completely on User Account. I opened a new browser and navigated to the user account for a random user - the labels still appear and the order has not been updated. I cleared cache - no difference. I ran cron - no difference. I subsequently updated a few modules and had to run update.php - no difference.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you edited the right viewmode? Have a look at the viewmodes which are enabled. Probably you moved the fields not on the viewmode "Full Content" (or "Full Profile") but on the "Default" instead. Or maybe the "Full Profile" is not activated?

Comment: Well - I checked the User account check box.  And everything shows on the user profile page - it just isn't updating my changes.  When I go back to /admin/config/people/accounts/display my changes do show there - just not on the actual user account pages.

Comment: AH!  So you pointed me right to the answer!  I had been clicking on the expandable Custom Display Settings and checking the User Account - thinking that would update the user account - silly me!  LOL  So as you insinuated - you must actually click on the User account "button"ish thing to the top right and then make the changes there.

Comment: Right, thats how you configure the different viewmodes :-)